# Is it possible to find the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue using the Ruffini rule?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

### **Take this matrix as an example:**

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 10 & 8 & 4 \\ -2 & 2 & -2 \\ -3 & -6 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$
$\det (A) = -\lambda^3 +15 \lambda^2 -72 \lambda +108$ (characteristic polynomial).

By applying the Ruffini rule it turns out that the eigenvalues are $3$ and $6$.
The solution given by the text says that $6$ has a multiplicity of two while $3$ of one, but how can I know that by applying Ruffini rule?

Comment: divide $(\lambda-3)|\det(A)$ or $(\lambda-6)|\det(A)$

Comment: When you apply Ruffini the final value is the evaluation of the polynomial, zero if the point was a root, but the intermediate values computed are the coefficients of the quotient. So, apply Ruffini again with those numbers. The number of times that you apply it and end up with a zero, is the order.

Comment: or jump into reality https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+-L%5E3%2B15+L%5E2-72+L%2B108

Comment: Thanks both, I got it now!